# Jenkins Linux dotnet not found

Tags: .net, jenkins

I reviewed a few topic related to issue mentioned on the title but still the problem is.
I installed plugin dotnet-sdk but the dotnet command not found. Only dotnet files in my jenkins docker are in var/jenkins_home/plugins and there is dotnet-sdk, dotnet-sdk.jpi.

I found that I should have dotnet file in usr/share/local but i don't have.
Manually instalation in cli is the only option to use dotnet command in jenkins ? I treated this option rather like a workaround but maybe this is only solution.
Very thanks for any answer!
Regards.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273682/jenkins-dotnet-command-not-found

Comment: export PATH=/usr/local/share/dotnet:$PATH doesn't works because i don't have dotnet file, net.sdk plugin instal also don't help me.